# How to set High charts series with X and Y value from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, highcharts

I don't know how to set series in x, y value from mysql database in High Charts. I want if data from my database show (umur:10 and berat: 5) then the node at x= 10 and y= 5 but i want x axis is number from 0 until 60. Please solve the problem.

**Grafik_model.php (Model)**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class grafik_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function tampil_grafik($id)
    {
        $q = $this->db->query("select a.*, b.* from balita a LEFT JOIN user b on a._id_user=b.u_id where b.u_id='".$id."' order by _umurbulan" );
        return $q;}}
```

**Grafik.php (Controller)**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Grafik extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url'));
        $this->load->library('Highcharts');
        $this->load->model('grafik_model');
    }
    function index()
    {

        $id= $this->session->userdata('u_id');
        $data=array();
        foreach($this->grafik_model->tampil_grafik($id)->result_array() as $row)
       // $data[] = (int) $row['_berat'];
        $data[] = array($row['_umurbulan'], (int) $row['_berat']);

        $this->load->view('grafik',array('data'=>$data));}}
```

**Grafik.php (View)**

```
    <html>
  <head>
  <title>Highcharts Tutorial</title>
  <script   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="container" style="width: 1350px; height: 1000px; margin: 0 auto">           </div>
  <script language="JavaScript">
  $(document).ready(function() {  
  var chart = {
  type: 'line'
  }; 
  var title = {
  text: 'Grafik Pertumbuhan Balita'   
  };
  var subtitle = {
  text: 'Berdasarkan umur dan berat'
  };
  var xAxis = {
   min: 0,
   max: 60,
   tickInterval: 1,
    reversed: false,
   title: {
     enabled: true,
     text: 'Umur (dalam bulan)'
     },
    labels: {
     formatter: function () {
        return this.value;
     }
     },
    maxPadding: 0.5,
    showLastLabel: true
    };
    var yAxis = {
    min: 0,
    max: 60,
    tickInterval: 1,
    title: {
     text: 'Berat (kg)'
    },
    labels: {
     formatter: function () {
        return this.value ;
     }
    },
    lineWidth: 2
    };
    var legend = {
    enabled: false 
    };
    var tooltip = {
   headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
   pointFormat: '{point.y}bulan:{point.x} kg: '
   };
   var plotOptions = {
    line: {
     marker: {
        enable: false
     }
      }
     };
   var series= [{
   name: 'Pertumbuhan Balita',
   data:  <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>

  }];      

  var json = {};
  json.chart = chart;
  json.title = title;
  json.subtitle = subtitle;
  json.legend = legend;
  json.tooltip = tooltip;
  json.xAxis = xAxis;
  json.yAxis = yAxis;  
  json.series = series;
  json.plotOptions = plotOptions;
  $('#container').highcharts(json);

  });
  </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: So you want a loop from 0 to 60?

Comment: No, have u seen the picture that i attached? In begin the graph show node at [0,5] but actually should show at [4,5] based on mysql database. So i want the node show the data based on mysql data.

Comment: You have to set json response according to highcharts series syntax. If you want to generate chart based on mysql data. you can also use jpgraph. It is a library and also available in php

Answer (score 1):

A very broad question. If I'm not wrong you are trying to plot a line chart with x-axis as **age (umur)** from 1 to 60 against y-axis as the **average weight (berat)** of an age. I can see you are encountering a few problems here.

1. Identify a type of Chart that suits your requirement. I would suggest to create a Line chart. Take a look at this [link](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) and get yourself familiar with Highcharts API.
2. You need to find yourself a way to query the average weight of age between 1 to 60 from your database. Community here has no clue about your data structure. Refer to the link in step1, click on `VIEW OPTIONS` button and focus on `xAxis` and `series` field. You need to construct two JSONs as following.

For your case, JSON format of `xAxis` would be something this which lists the age from 1 to 60.

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', ...., '59', '60']
}
```

Whereas `series` is as below which lists out the weights

```
series: [{
    name: 'Weight',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, ..., 50.2, 55.3]
}]
```

So in the end each array of `xAxis` and `series.data` has total of 60 elements and their values are corresponding to each other.

3. Refer to the link in step1 and create the Line chart accordingly in your **View**.

Comment: I have updated my full code for **View**. But the result is the graph cannot catch the data for umur (age), just catch data for berat (weight). So the graph begins from 0 of x axis

Comment: Post your code in jsFiddle and we start from there. I'm not familiar with PHP but I will try my best to help out.

Comment: this the link https://jsfiddle.net/eh6k07rw/6/ but i dont know how to put in MVC.

Comment: @VeraFarhanah take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/eh6k07rw/8/ I updated the series.data field. Just make sure your JSON is similar to what I demonstrated with 61 elements since your x-axis starts from 0 to 60.

Comment: Ok thank you @Wilts. But how if the data get from mysql and have 2 values?  like this http://jsfiddle.net/eh6k07rw/13/ but i want the data get from mysql.

Comment: @VeraFarhanah What does the 2 data represent? Weight and what? You might need two lines in your chart for this.

Comment: 2 data represent weight and age but i need one line. If i put one data as weight, the graph doesnt follow the x axis as a represent of age in mysql. Do u get what i mean?

Comment: @VeraFarhanah I see. As what I mention in my answer you have to find a way to query out the weights of age between 0-60 and construct the JSON in ascending order. Make sure your JSON is something like this [13, 15, 17, 18....., 60] whereby 13=0 month, 15=1 month, 17=2 month and so on.

Comment: But i dont want the value like 13=0 month, 15=1 month, and so on. I need the value of month based on mysq,l such as in mysql the data show that the child-1 has 13 weight and 10 month, child-2 has 8 weight and 7 month, and child-3 has 15 weight and 9 month. So the graph show that and not begin at 0 on x axis. Please help me :)

Comment: I think you have to get your idea correct first. As per what you commented there is now a new dimension called 'Child', in which to me sounds like there is no way to plot a chart based on your requirement. I can plot one with Age vs Weight vs Sex (F,M) but not Age vs Weight vs Child since there could be hundreds of different Child data.

Comment: Oya sorry I think i had mistake, I mean that in mysql there are weight and month, such as row 1 = weight 5, month 2, row 2= weight 10, month 20, row 3= weight 7, month 10, and so on according user input. So on graph i will show the weight and the month based on user login. User can see his/her data.from the graph @WiltsC

Comment: Can u give me a suggestion?